# Sum interpretation

Tags: summation

Is the interpretation of
$$
\sum_{1 \leq j-1 \leq n}a_{j-1}
$$
in that stile
$$
\sum_{j-1=n}^{n}a_{j-1}
$$
correct ?
Can somebody give me a numerical example of that sum, please ?

Comment: I would say $
\sum_{j-1=1}^{n}a_{j-1}
$ OR with index shift $j-1=m$ $\Rightarrow
\sum_{m=1}^{n}a_{m}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{n} a_j$$